# How should I specify the app id?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have an application which runs in Google App Engine.

At first the app could be run using:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Where `app.yaml` contained the field `application` which would be used to retrieve the project id using `google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_application_id()`.

Later the `dev_appserver.py` command was removed and the app could be run using:

```
gcloud preview app run app.yaml
```

Running this resulted into a warning that specifying `application` in `app.yaml` is deprecated.

Now `app run` has been deprecated in favour of the now restored `dev_appserver.py`. Does this mean I should restore the `application` field in `app.yaml` as well?

If I run `gcloud config list` it still shows the correct project id, but calling `google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_application_id()` returns `None` if `application` is not set.

Comment: *calling google.appengine.api.app_identity.get_application_id() returns None* is that with or without specifying `application` in app.yaml? If I don't specify it it returns `None` but if I do it returns the name as expected (hi btw)

Comment: I updated the question to answer your comment

Comment: You can specify `-A <APP_ID>` with `dev_appserver.py` - does that help? Would welcome clarification from Google on recommended practise though.  All the changes to the dev tools make this *very* confusing (`appcfg`, `dev_appserver`, `gcloud`, `mvn:appengine`, `mvn:gcloud`...)

Answer (score 2):

The `application` property in `.yaml` config files is well supported, in fact it's
present in all module configuration file examples in the [Modules documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/).

Specifying the app name using the `application` property is arguably less error prone than using the otherwise mandatory `-A <APP_ID` command line argument to some/all related utilities.

Attempting to upload a module config file with the `application` field commented out shows:

```
appcfg.py: error: Expected -A app_id when application property in file main.yaml is not set.
```

Which I'd interpret as suggesting that using the `application` property in a module's `.yaml` file would be the default/preferred approach.

FWIW, the `application` property is also applicable to other configuration files - I had some trouble when I added routing by `dispatch.yaml` in my multi-module app, resolved by adding the `application` property to the `dispatch.yaml` file. I don't recall the exact details, tho.

Comment: I know it is possible and convenient to specify `application` in `app.yaml`, but I would like to see an official statement about this being undeprecated. Also thanks for saying `application` is also applicable to other config files. I didn't know this and find this very useful.

Comment: At this point `gcloud preview app` is still a beta release: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app#Deploying_app. The deprecation message may be just an oversight. I wouldn't worry too much, especially since the established/released GAE tools (`dev_appserver.py`, `appcfg.py`) don't mention any such deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) now says the the `application` property is deprecated and you should use the `-A` option of `dev_appserver.py`.